# Limited memory priority queue

Tags: c++, optimization

I'm trying to implement a highly efficient limited memory priority queue. The interface is the same as a `std::priority_queue`.

Can anyone suggest any performance improvements on my attempt?

**limited_queue.h**

```
#include <array>
#include <algorithm>

template<typename T, std::size_t N>
class LimitedPriorityQueue
{
public:
    LimitedPriorityQueue() {}

    void push(T item)
    {
        if (next != items.end()) {
            *next = item;
            ++next;
            std::push_heap(items.begin(), next);
        } else {
            std::sort_heap(items.begin(), items.end());
            if (items.front() < item) {
                items[0] = item;
            }
            std::make_heap(items.begin(), items.end());
        }
    }

    T top()
    {
        return items.front();
    }

    void pop()
    {
        std::pop_heap(items.begin(), next);
        --next;
    }

    bool empty()
    {
        return size() == 0;
    }

    std::size_t size()
    {
        return next - items.begin();
    }

private:
    std::array<T, N> items;
    T* next = items.begin();
};
```

**main.cpp**

```
#include "limited_queue.h"

int main()
{
    LimitedPriorityQueue<int, 10> queue;

    for (int i = 20; i >= 0; --i) {
        queue.push(i);
    }

    while (!queue.empty()) {
        std::cout << queue.top() << std::endl;
        queue.pop();
    }
}
```

Also, I wasn't quite telling the truth when I said the interface is the same as a `std::priority_queue`; I'm missing an `emplace`. I'm not sure if this is possible using an underlying `std::array`?

Comment: Methods that don't mutate class state such as `size()`, `empty()`, `top()` should be `const`. E.g.: `bool empty() const`

Comment: Also, you might want to take a look at [`noexcept`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/noexcept)

Comment: What are the performance issues with an std::priority_queue that you're trying to overcome with your design? If you're just trying to avoid dynamic memory allocation with vector why not just reserve space in the vector up front?

Comment: @mattnewport It's a memory issue - I have a huge number of records that I'd like to rank. It's unlikely all the values will fit into main memory, so I ask for the N best instead.

Comment: So what's the actual problem you're trying to solve? Is it like a kth smallest problem?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Overall, it looks great. The code is clear and easy to follow, you leveraged the standard library well, and performance should be decent decent. There are however, a few things that could be improved.

---

It might be worth templating the comparison. All that you would have to change is passing an extra argument to `make_heap`, `pop_head` and `push_heap`. There's really not much of a reason to not template the comparator unless I'm missing something.

---

`top()` should return a const reference. No reason to make the user copy it unless they want.

---

You've allowed for move semantics by taking a value rather than const reference in push, but you haven't taken advantage of it the whole way through. Your assignments should be move assignments since you know you're done with the values. That lets you avoid a potentially expensive copy assignment.

---

Speaking of movement.... You are correct that can't meaningfully implement an `emplace` with an `std::array`. Since the elements are default constructed, there's no blank slot to construct in place in to. The best you could do would be a move assignment into an already constructed element which is the same performance as using `push` with move semantics.

What you could do, however, is use `std::aligned_storage` and emplace into that. It's basically a tool for getting unitialized memory that's ripe for having something constructed into it. From there, you can implement `emplace` just like you would in a non-stack allocated situation.

Unfortunately your other logic would get a bit more complicated, but not much. Only construction and destruction (i.e. `push` and `pop`) would change, and they would only need placement new and manual-destruction.

There's a pretty good example of what I'm talking about at on cppreference's [`std::aligned_storage`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/aligned_storage) page, though it unfortunately does not have an `emplace` example.

---

One last, highly subjective thing: I would probably name it `BoundedPriorityQueue` instead of `LimitedPriorityQueue`. Limited sounds like limited functionality to me, whereas bounded sounds like having a maximum size (like bounded buffer).

Also, it might be worth throwing in a bit of documentation. It's pretty obvious from the name and the template params, but someone could wonder what happens when it's full (example thrown, or chucking out the lowest element).

Answer (score 2):

While the code is ok (and Corbin's answer covers most of the ways it could be improved) I think this class is a poor abstraction to efficiently solve most of the kinds of problems you might use it for.

In the comments you mention using it to solve something like the k smallest problem and this data structure is sub-optimal for that. If you have n elements and you want to find the 'best' (read smallest from now on) k elements where n >> k then you will be doing many more pushes than pops and you will never pop until you reach the end of the input. Your data structure does extra k log k work on each push when it is full however (which will be most of the time for this problem) that is completely wasted.

If on the other hand you want something to use like a traditional priority queue (intermingling pushes and pops while processing the input) then your data structure will give you arbitrarily bad answers for certain inputs (where bad means the items you end up processing will be worse than arbitrarily many items you 'lost' due to overflow). In such a situation, if you want to get as close as possible to processing the actual best elements you should keep growing your queue dynamically whenever you push elements until you actually exhaust memory rather than choosing some arbitrary bound in advance.

In summary, I don't think this is a generally useful data structure and if you are more specific about the problem you're actually trying to solve then I'm confident you could solve it much more efficiently using a different approach.